# Generate Page / User access token for Facebook API without redirecting

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-rest-api

I am trying to use Facebook Rest API in my application . I wanted to generate authentication token and using that generate page access token which can be used to post on page.
When I was going through the authentication process I found that all authentication flow uses redirection to main Facebook application. I want to have an authentication flow in which I don’t have to redirect to generate authentication toke and page token. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: To get an access token, the user has to visit facebook.com in one way or another (could be via redirect, could be the login dialog in a popup).

Comment: PS - Don't build on the REST API anymore, its being deprecated https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/